# Can I plaster and paint over wallpaper?

Tags: drywall, walls, plaster, patching-drywall

I have a 20cm hole in a wallpapered wall.

Can I get away with filling the wall with plaster, then painting over it, without stripping the wallpaper off the entire wall first?

Or must I strip the wallpaper first?[image]

Comment: Quite a few questions have already been asked on this subject. See https://diy.stackexchange.com/search?q=paint+over+wallpaper.

Comment: I was thinking of removing the paper in a square just outside the dammage, not the entire wall. Then filling the hole up to the paper before using really fine wire wool to blend it in. Will this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. With a fresh utility knife blade cut through the wall paper around the area you wish to repair. It can be any shape, but give yourself some margin, say a few inches away from the edge of the brittled or cracked areas.

Shmoo shapes are best. (What's a [Shmoo](https://www.google.com/search?q=Shmoo) you ask?)

2. Within that area peel off the wall paper and anything that comes with it. Make sure you don't peel outside the area, and re-cut as needed.
3. Perform drywall repairs with proper backing as needed (drywall board on wooden backing, or mud on backing etc.., depending what's behind the hole)
4. Patch and smooth with a finishing drywall compound and feather lightly into the existing painted area. Sand as needed.
5. Prime and paint.

Textures may not match.

If you need more tips on the plastering / mudding part, let us know. Compounds come in different packaging (bags, tubs) and types (setting vs drying), and some are better for this task than others.

Comment: I did this and it worked perfectly, thankyou!

Comment: @reggie thanks for providing feedback. Useful to all readers!